# Is there a way to deny a custom expression from being written using Rubocop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to install a cache layer, this cache layer should be preferred to certain Rails Model Methods like `find_by_id`.

I want to use Rubocop to make sure newcomers won't write `find_by_id` using q model, for example: don't write `Customer.find_by_id` and instead be forced to use `CustomerCache.find_by_id`

Can I do it Rubocop? I'm fairly new to ruby and rails, and all it's ecosystem

Thank you!

Comment: So you're asking how to write your own extension? https://www.rubocop.org/en/stable/extensions/

Answer (score 1):

Rubocop is a good tool to indicate Ruby programming patterns that should be followed or avoided. This particular use case does not belong in the Rubocop layer IMO as it is not a Ruby programming pattern, and is tied to your particular implementation.

A couple of patterns you can use to handle this:

1. Add a deprecation warning any time somebody calls the method

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  def find_by_id(*args)
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Customers should be retrieved through CustomerCache"
    super
  end
end
```

2. Delegate the method call to the object which should be handling it

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  def find_by_id(*args)
    CustomerCache.find_by_id(*args)
  end
end
```

Can also consider removing the method altogether.

Comment: `CustomerCache` probably has to call the original method(s). How would that work using your proposed solutions?

Comment: @Stefan Good point. First (horrible) solution that comes to mind would be to rename the original method and have `CustomerCache` call that. Alternative would be to have a conditional flag on the delegating method (eg. `cache: false` which controls whether the call goes through `CustomerCache`. Consider whether `CustomerCache` is a first class concept of its own (respect `Customer` restrictions and load records through SQL or otherwise) or an implementation detail within `Customer` (in which case `Customer` is free to choose any internal implementation which preserves the public interface).